# Elementary Set Theory: Verifying uniqueness of isomorphism between ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $W$ be a set and $E$ be a binary relation on $W$ satisfying the following properties:

(a) For all $x, y \in W$, if for every $z \in W$, $z \in x$ if and only if $z \in y$, then $x = y$.

(b) $E$ is well-founded

I am trying to prove that there is a unique transitive set $M$ and unique function $π$ with domain $W$ such that $π$ is an isomorphism from $(W, E)$ to $(M, \in)$.

I have been given the answer using $π(x) = \{π(y)\, |\, yEx\}$.

I don't know why this works.  I have plugged in $x_{0}$ the minimum element of $W$, and then $x_{1}$ the minimum element of  $W\setminus x_{0}$, etc... And I have something that resembles the sup, but instead I have $\pi(x_{i+1})$ = $\sup \pi(x_{i})$ $\cup$ $\pi(x_{i+1})$.  So I can say that there is an bijection between $W$ and $M$ which preserves order as needed.

Is this correct so far? Either way, I don't know how to show uniqueness.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: (a) should be with respect to $E$, not $\in$. It should read:
$$
\text{For all $x, y \in W$, if for every $z \in W$, $z E x$ if and only if $z E y$, then $x = y$.}
$$
The usual term for this is: "$E$ is *extensional*".

Comment: @Mary Did you check that $\pi$ is injective?

Answer (score 1):

Answer on the uniqueness.

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are both transitive sets and that the structures
$\langle M,\in_{M}\rangle$ and $\langle N,\in_{N}\rangle$ are isomorphic. Let $f$ denote this isomorphism. Then we have:

$\forall m\forall m'\left[m'\in_{M}m\iff f\left(m'\right)\in_{N}f\left(m\right)\right]$.

The fact that $M$ and $N$ are both transitive allows us to modificate
this statement:

$\forall m\in M\forall m'\left[m'\in m\iff f\left(m'\right)\in f\left(m\right)\right]$

Every $x\in f\left(m\right)\in N$ is also an element of $N$ (because $N$ is transitive) and the surjectivity
of $f$ ensures that $x=f\left(m'\right)$ for some $m'\in N$.

This together allows the conclusion that:

$\forall m\in M\left[f\left(m\right)=\left\{ f\left(m'\right)\mid m'\in m\right\} \right]$.

Based on this we can prove with $\in$-induction that:

$\forall m\in M\left[f\left(m\right)=m\right]$.